# Trouble with overtime program

Tags: java

I think I did it all correct however im having an error. Very confused. 
Error: overtime.java:10: error: variable pay might not have been initialized
         displayResults(pay);

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Overtime {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hours;
        double rate, pay;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        displayResults(pay);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print( "Enter how many hours worked: " );
        hours = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print( "Enter hourly rate: " );
        rate = in.nextDouble();
    }

    public double calculatePay( int hours, double rate, double pay ) {
        if ( hours > 40 ) { 
            int extraHours = hours - 40;
            pay = ( 40 * rate ) + ( extraHours * rate * 1.5);
        } else
            pay = hours * rate;
        return pay;
    }

    public static void displayResults(double pay) {
        System.out.printf( "\nGross Salary: %f", pay);
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `displayResults(pay)` before setting `pay` to a value.

Comment: You should do something about your formatting; this is a mess. Apply proper indentation to make it better readable. And please follow the Java Naming Conventions; class names should always be in PascalCase.

Comment: double pay=0; (quick fix)

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your `main` has to reordered:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hours;
    double rate, pay;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print( "Enter how many hours worked: " );
    hours = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print( "Enter hourly rate: " );
    rate = in.nextDouble();

    pay = ;// call calculatePay here

    displayResults(pay);
}
```

And you have to remove the `pay` parameter of the `calculatePay` method. Its declaration should be

```
public static double calculatePay( int hours, double rate )
```

Comment: did what you told me and im now getting this error: overtime.java:15: error: non-static method calculatePay(int,double,double) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @unattainable ah, yes, the last "bug", make it static, edited the answer

Comment: @unattainable the error you are now getting hints that you didn't delete last argument from the method (the second double argument).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is the fact you didn't assign any value to variable `pay`and you called a method `displayResults()` which needs this variable as an argument. Firstly you should calculate `pay` value with `calculatePay` (but you should delete `double pay` from list of arguments passed to this method, because there is no need to place it there).

After calculations made with `calculatePay()` and having its result in `pay` variable you can call `displayResults()` without problem.

Another problem is that `calculatePay()` need to made `static` and **both your methods should be declared outside of the main() method body** (the bold part of my answer is no longer relevant, because bad looking indentation made me a bit confused and I thought that methods were declared inside the `main()` method).

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like a homework. So Iam providing only guidance:

1. Initialize all variables first and set them to values. (eg. double pay=1; ) and drop the Scanner.
2. Once this is working - add the Scanner and display all variables with System.out.format(...).
3. Once vars are displayed properly (point2) and (1)works - connect variables set by the Scanner with rest of your code

Good luck! :-)